# Setting document library permissions in WSS 2.0

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I am using WSS2.0. Am trying to set some permissions to a document library but not getting the desired behavior. I have created a sharepoint user and assigned it to 'Reader' group. I just want this user to view document library content but not make any changes like check out or upload new document or delete etc. Hence I assign the Reader group. But when I login to the site as this user I am able to delete documents and perform other changes. I checked the document library permissions and it contains Reader, Contributor, Administrator groups and also the permissions are not inherited from the parent.

Is there any other settings I need to check. Have I missed or misunderstood anything?

Please advise.

Thanks,
Jagannath

Answer (score 0):

Based on the details provided it seems likely that the user in question also belongs to another group (local, Active Directory or SharePoint) with the additional permissions.

Comment: I have checked that the user only belongs to 'Users' local group. I even tried by creating a new local group and assigning the user to it. But still no luck. Is there something I have overlooked?

Thanks,
Jagannath